# CenturyLink Modem and Wifi with Google WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking

CenturyLink is my ISP. They provided a modem with built in WiFi. Currently I am using Netgear for my in-house wifi and am planning to replace it with Google. Being a mesh network, can I have the same connection to the CenturyLink modem with Google as I do now with my Netgear and still use the CenturLink wifi also? Basically, my set up, is I am either hardwired to the modem or using the built in wifi for all my PCs and the NetGear for all my entertainment systems. I want the same reult when google is installed. I did try to mesh google and netgear together, but all that got me was an afternoon of rebuilding my wifi back on netgear.

Comment: How did you go about setting up the Google mesh network? What problems did you face to where you had to revert back to the Netgear? The Netgear network and the Google network should have their own SSID so you should be able to use both if you wish, however, that kind of defeats the purpose of having the Google mesh network.

Comment: Originally, I though I was buying extenders. That was no big deal.  I think where I went wrong is that I tried to bridge the two together. THat was where the problems started. I had toake google out of the picture and rebuild the nrtgear network along with the extender I had in the upstairs area. THere were acouple of times that the router froze and had to reboot, which for some reason caused me to where configure. Now since I have google, I will hust replce netgear with it.

Comment: They are extenders, but what you need to do is connect one of the Google Wifi nodes to your modem directly. Then you can place the other two in your household to give better coverage. [Setting up Google Wifi](https://support.google.com/wifi/answer/7183148?hl=en)

Comment: So basically, I just be replacing the Netgear with Google and keeping CenturyLink, thus having two separate Wi-Fis as before.

Comment: Yes. You'll plug one of the Google Wifi nodes into your CentruyLink modem, and then you can place the other two into the wall in other rooms in the home. If you do set up the Google, you can turn the Netgear wifi off. If you need more help or explanation let me know and I can create a chat room.